# Android studio emulator launch on VM

Tags: android-emulator

Dear team facing attached error while launching emulator on VM. I Have attached error screenshot and System specification. [Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMvnq.png)
[System specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ5rV.jpg)

I tried to launch emulator on on VM DESKTO OS 11 we created on Nutanix AHV. Facing error